# Problem on Normal Distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

My homework problem is as follows: I start with a string of 0's of length $n$. Then, with probability $p$, I change each bit to 1 identically and independently. After that, I count the number of 1's in the string (which, on average, will be $np$). Let the number of 1's be $P_1$. Continue this process 100 times, get integers $P_1, P_2,\ldots, P_{100}$. I want to estimate maximum in the set $\{P_1, P_2, .., P_{100}\}$.

Comment: Since you have used the `normal-distribution` tag, which part of the problem do _you_ think involves the normal distribution?

Comment: I added the "homework" tag. If this is not homework, you can remove it.

Comment: Hint: what distribution does the number of 1s in the string follow?

Comment: Number of 1 follows binomial distribution follows. As binomial approach to Normal, I use normal distribution tag.

Comment: Two questions, 1) do you reset each iteration so that the string is back to zeros? 2) Can we presume your prof. would want you to program this rather than obtain an analytic expression?

Comment: 1. Before each iteration string is back to 0. 
2. I observed the result experimentally, I am trying for theoretical bound.

Comment: @user12290 Look into [order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know that each of the $P_i$ ($i=1,2,\ldots,100$) follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$. According to your comments and your question tags, you also know that each of these binomials can be approximated by a normal distribution. You haven't mentioned the parameters for these normals, but they aren't too hard to determine: it's reasonable to think that these normals should have the same expected value and variance as the original binomial distributions. Each $P_i$ is approximately normally distributed with parameters $\mu=np$ and $\sigma^2=np(1-p)$.

Now you've defined a new random variable $T$ as the maximum of $P_1,\ldots,P_{100}$. I'm assuming you want to estimate the expected value of $T$, $\textrm{E}\left[T\right]$. I've always found the most straightforward approach for similar problems to be the following.

1. Try to calculate the cumulative density function for $T$ by rewriting $P(T\leq t)$ in terms of the other random variables in the problem ($P_1,\ldots,P_{100}$). Hint: If the maximum of a set of numbers is bounded above by $t$, what can you say about the bounds on the individuals in the set?
2. Calculate the probability density function by differentiating the cumulative density function found in the previous step.
3. Now you should be able to write down an integral representing the expected value of $T$. Evaluating the integral may be difficult (as I believe it is in this case), but nothing is stopping you from using numerical integration.

Sometimes it helps to work backwards. You want $\textrm{E}\left[T\right]=\textrm{E}\left[\max(P_1,\ldots,P_{100})\right]$. The expected value of a random variable is written as $\textrm{E}\left[T\right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tf_T(t)dt$. To calculate the integral you need to know the density of $T$, $f_T(t)$. For me, it's always been more simple to calculate the density by differentiating the CDF, but I'm sure there are other simple ways to calculate it too.